# How to iterate over the list of words in a MS Word 2010 document with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

What I'm actually trying to do is implementing a button to compute the [Gunning fog index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunning_fog_index). What I would normally do in anything other than VBA is:

1. Provide a dictionary of words considered to be "complex" (to be compiled from professional jargon that should be used only when necessary)
2. Get the list of words in the document.
3. Determine the length of this list.
4. Get the number of sentences (possibly just the number of "dot whitespace" occurrences) and determine the average words/sentence
5. Filter the list of words the "complex" words and compare the length of the "complex word list" with the length of the "word list".

What I don't know how to do is how to get an object "this documents.wordList", and what are the "length", and "filter is-complex" methods would be.

This doesn't need to be specially elegant, it's for personal use only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Find` method, combined with a counter that adds 1 to itself each time a word is found, could provide a list of complex words in the document. The length would simply be the counter at the end of the search.

The `Words.Count` property will return the number of all words in the document. Similarly you could do `Sentences.Count` for the number of sentences.

This should get you pointed in the right direction. Visit the [Word VBA help files](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helphome.aspx?lcid=1033&NS=WINWORD%2EDEV&Version=12) for more info on this and other possibilities.